# CSS on iPad - how to make both orientations behave the same?

Tags: css

I have some CSS in my bootstrap menu.css that makes the menu very different in wide mode compared with narrow mode. I want both to behave as in narrow mode. Here is the selector block:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
     ... a bunch of css
}
```

It's easy to [see this in action here](http://www.herrimandeals.com/).

1. Open that page in Chrome
2. Hit F12 for Chrome developer tools
3. Click the Mobile icon
4. Choose iPad from the pulldown

Notice that in narrow mode the menu looks like this (which I want):

[image]

Ok, now click the orientation icon in chrome dev tools to rotate the ipad viewer, and you'll see this much taller menu (this is wrong):

[image]

I suspect that a tweak in that CSS selector would force the wide menu to look like the narrow menu, but I can't figure out how to do it. In fact the ideal would be for the wide menu to look just like full PC (non-tablet) menu, but expand and navigate correctly. When I revert to PC-size menu on ipad, it looks good but you can't navigate to sub-menus. So option A would be ok, but option B would be awesome if there's a way.

Any ideas?